# Failed to run PHP with MongoDB Extension (PHP 5.3.8 , OS: Centos 5.4)

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a problem on running PHP's MongoDB extensions

**Read the solution at the end of this post**

I successfully installed it using 3 different methods but it doesn't show the extension in phpinfo()

1-Using pecl install mongo ( it succeeded and asked me to add extension=mongo.so) in php.ini
2-By downloading the source the compiling it.
3-From yum installing php-pecl-mongo

All methods succeed without errors but when I run phpinfo I don't see the Mongo extension loaded and when I try to call it asks for installing the extension.

How do I debug this issue (i.e. Where can I find such logs)

And how do I Find info about Mongo's compatibility with PHP 5.3.8 ?

This is what I get at the end of the installation :

**Notice: I'm sure that I copied the mongo.so file to the extension path of php as I'm using other extension from the same dir and they're working**

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /sources/mongo/mongodb-mongo-php-driver-d7c19b8/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts                                                -20060613/
-bash-3.2# cp /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/mongo.so /
```

---

**Fixed --> the issue was that my php api wasn't the same version as PHP i.e. php-devel/php5-devel needed to be updated.**

Comment: Did you run `phpize` before compiling?

Comment: yes

phpize
then ./configure
then make install

Comment: Ahhh didn't see your NOTICE. Can you confirm what I added in my post, and if you are sure that it was accomplished, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile a module manually you have to copy it to a path which PHP knows where to look for custom modules.

From the cli, try this command:

```
php -i | fgrep -i configure
```

You should see an option like:

```
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/bridge/to/nowhere
```

Make sure, after you compile the module, that you copy the module from the mongo source directory, to the /bridge/to/nowhere directory, so PHP can pick it up.

With any luck, it should be listed when you do a `php -m`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the '`extension=mongo.so`' line in your php.ini file to:

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/mongo.so
```

When php starts up, does it produce any error message?  If not, please verify that `php -i |grep -e 'Loaded Configuration File'` shows the expected php.ini file.

The mongodb php extension should work just fine with php v5.3.8 (and php-fpm).

Comment: It says : Loaded Configuration File => (none)

Comment: How do you start php?  Try starting it with a path to the config file (e.g. `php -c /path/to/php.ini -i |grep mongo`).

Comment: I did so even set the config ini option in both pecl & pear, phpinfo shows the correct path of the ini file and other extensions that are placed in the same extensions dir are working fine but not mongo.so I'm givin up on mongo, really thinking about switching to couchDB :S

Comment: If the path is correct but the module won't load, PHP should print a warning like:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/mongo.so'`.  Is this the case?

Comment: This---> php -c /etc/php.ini -i |grep mongo  ----> displays mongo correctly. . . while when I use php for the web not the CLI it showns that the loaded config file is /etc/php.ini and mongo is not loaded and doesn't give errors . .

Comment: Web meaning apache and mod_php?  Check your web servers logs (access.log and error.log if apache)